# Limited Dissolve changes vertex positions?

Tags: modeling, vertices

Carry over from a [youtube video comment here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIcvA5B-N3U&lc=Ugyy3PB0jjYiP6iM8v94AaABAg.9A8OJcY0QtQ9DsDXlOQiyN)

In the video, the presenter manually fills in an example with edges to make faces. A commenter suggested using `Alt-F` to fill and then `Limited Dissolve` to reduce the mesh. As this is a video on precision modeling, I was surprised to see vertex positions of the bevels and circles on a simple 10mm plane with 4 holes were changed.  Is there a way to dissolve edges without changing vertex positions?

Blend file for reference; 1 degree + 5 degree dissolves

[image]

**Edit**: Thanks to Robin and taking a second look, I realize now that Blender uses single precision floats instead of double... so that explains my scripts output differing. Don't use 5 degree (default?) with `Limited Dissolve` and you get great output.

Comment: Hi! Well, this is a mystery. I can get no changes of location, only deletions as you would expect, in a diff. output. 2.8, 2.9, your script and mine, all steps.  I've added my script to [your file, here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/88KpBJ4V/), just in case it makes a difference to the diff. for you. If the problem persists, ??

Comment: Hey Robin!

Here's my findings: `Limited Dissolve` at 5 degrees leads to large changes that you can see in the example blend file. 1 degree leads to smaller, but measurable differences. Selecting all but a handful of edges and dissolving them leads to nothing moving (yay!), and of course hand-drawing the lines has the same results.  Reloading the file will lead to differences measured only in floating point values (5th decimal or 100,000th of a millimeter) which is expected with floats.

Comment: Your script has better output; I'm happy to stick with 1 degree or less on limited dissolve.

Comment: @RobinBetts - if you leave an answer, I'm happy to mark it as the solution. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Glad there's a satisfactory-(ish) outcome! You found it.. you can answer your own question, and mark it as accepted, if you prefer. It will be useful to others who run into the same anomaly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Robin, his script, and taking a second look, I realize now that Blender uses single precision floats instead of double. In the first python script, it is printing whatever python thinks (double precision).

1. Don't use 5 degree (default?) with Limited Dissolve. This lead to original vertices being deleted.
2. Less than 1 degree limited dissolve doesn't have this problem.